# Cannot open an IIS website from Visual Studio 2019 - The Web Server cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, azure, iis

I am migrating from an old Windows 2008 r2 box to a new Azure VM. I have installed the website in IIS and this is all working ok, bar one page, where a chart control is not quite right.
When i try to open the IIS website from within Visual studio i get the following error:

Error opening Web https://10.1.0.4 unable to open the website https://10.1.0.4 The web server could not be found.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8dHJ.png)

I have installed all the relevant frameworks, am running Visual studio as admin, and have debuging enabled in my web.config, although all the files etc are a direct copy of the old site just under a new IP. I also tried using Visual Studio 2017 as this was the version on our old server. I have turned off the windows firewall as a test and nothing seems to work!

If anyone has any ideas i'd be most grateful :) Thanks
Simon

Comment: To confirm, this is Visual Studio installed within the VM?

Comment: What type of Azure VM is this? A Cloud Service VM, an ARM (Azure Resource Manager) VM, or a "Classic" VM?

Comment: Run some basic diagnostics and edit your question to include key points from the report, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: Coudl you please tell me how you open the IIS website from within Visual studio? Do you want to use remote debug to remote debug the IIS web site on the remote Azure server?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for coming back :) I am using an azure VM with Visual Studio 2019 installed on the machine, its not a classic one, was purchased as a SQL Virtual Machine. To Open the site, i am going to File Open, choosing Website, I then choose the IIS option (as per my old server) it then list my two sites (web service and web site) i then choose the one i want to debug and it comes back after a few seconds with the error shown. I ill go through the diagnostics document and give that a try as well Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Just to clarify what im trying to achive, I have an issue where if i open the site by choosing the website option and selecting the folder, when i run this everything works perfectly (im feeding data into a scatter chart) if it just run the live website thats running under IIS the chart fails to load the data. Im assuming there is somehting maybe region related possibly linked to IIS (ive check the normal settings and they seem to be as i expect)so i wanted to open the actual IIS site, put a stop on the code that feeds the chart and see what happens when i load the site via the public website.

Comment: Apologies, In terms of the diagnostics bit, as i am attempting to open the actual IIS site, it wont load the site at all hence i cant click on the diagostics bit, it will not load the site at all! Im assuming it must be some kind of permissions thing, but ive turned of the windows firewall! I've not touched the standard azure firewall though however as both IIS and Visual studio are on the machine, and im connecting via the private IP I didnt think it would get that far? Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Everyone, I have managed to resolve this (at least temporarily) If i change the bindings in IIS from the individual IP address to any i can then link open the website as i require. For the now this will enable me to resolve the issue im getting! If anyone has any ideas why a * IP binding works but choosing an actual IP doesnt i would be most grateful! Going forward the server will have multiple IP's for different sites, so of couse i cant leave it on bound using a * Thanks for the help so far, Simon

Comment: @SimonMilne Glad you are not blocked by this anymore. Please summarize your findings as an answer below so it can help others in the community who might have similar questions. Thanks!